# view pdf without downloading using dompdf

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

I generated a PDF using the dompdf library and used this:

```
$dompdf->stream('my.pdf',array('Attachment'=>0));
```

to force the browser to let the user view the PDF before downloading. But it's not working. A Google search isn't bringing up any answers either. Can anyone help?

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by "not working"? What happens instead?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Try using the below code. **Let me know are you create data from form or html file data.**

```
$dompdf->stream("dompdf_out.pdf", array("Attachment" => false));

exit(0);
```

Comment: Seems like you don't need `exit(0);`. With `$dompdf->stream("dompdf_out.pdf");` the file gets dowloaded. With `$dompdf->stream("dompdf_out.pdf", array("Attachment" => false));` the file gets shown in the browser.

Comment: Exit is important in stream. Just found this answer and it's working. Saved day, but spent 4 hours to find!

Answer (score 4):

If someone still looking for answer and it's still not resolved, try installing and turning on the PDF Viewer / PDF JS extension in the browser.

After adding parameter `array(“Attachment”=>0)` or `array(“Attachment”=>false)` to the **stream** and still not working. It's because your browser doesn't have a pdf reader available/activated. Installing and activating browser extension like PDF Viewer / PDFJS will force the browser to read and review the pdf.

Comment: Please add some further explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: if parameter array(“Attachment”=>0) or array(“Attachment”=>false) isn't working it's because the pdf reader in the browser isn't available. PDFJS extension will force the browser to read and review the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$dompdf->stream("", array("Attachment" => false));
```

Instead of

```
$dompdf->stream();
```

It worked for me