# HTML/PHP DOMPDF: output to the browser seems not recognized from firefox

Tags: php, html, dompdf

I'm creating a PDF from an html page.

it works perfectly on chrome, edge and opera but on firefox it has a weird behaviour.
It seems not to recognize the statement to output to the browser (preview) but it asks to open/save the output...

this is my code:

```
<?php
    ob_start();

    $id = $_GET['id'];

    require "./mypage.php"; 
    $html = ob_get_clean();

    // include autoloader
    require_once './dompdf/autoload.inc.php';

    //Reference of Dompdf namespace
    use Dompdf\Dompdf;
    use Dompdf\Options;
    
    // instantiate and use the dompdf class
    $options = new Options();
    $options->set('enable_html5_parser', true);
    $options->set('isJavascriptEnabled', true);

    $dompdf = new Dompdf($options);

    //Create PDF
    $dompdf->loadHtml($html);

    // Render the HTML as PDF
    $dompdf->render();

    $output = $dompdf->output();

    // Output the generated PDF to Browser
    $dompdf->stream($output, array("Attachment" => false));
    exit(0);
?>
```

no problems with chrome opera or edge.
(my firefox version is 94.0.1) –

what can it be?
thanks

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61864953/128761) answer your question?

Comment: yes vee, I caught just for that post to write my code but unfortunately I think that KJ is right and this is a setting of the browser. Do you think that is there any chance, from dompdf, to force the browser to preview instead of download?

Comment: I try with mPDF, it's browser problem as K J said. :-)